# Select value if exist otherwise load default

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

This is my table :

[image: table]

I want fetch default 5 records from particular area if exist otherwise any default records, if 2 records are existing then 3 are any randomly need to fetch. If 4 are there then 1 is any randomly. e.g.if I am trying to fetch `mumbai` then first 2 are '**mumbai**' and another 3 are any random record fetched from table. suppose I want to fetch by '**washington**' then there is no record so all 5 records are need to fetch randomly.

So how can I do this?

I hope you understand what I want to say. If not then you can ask me.

Thanks.

Comment: you should provide some code you tried at least.. We're not here to do what you can't achieve. We're here to help you fix what you've done wrong.

Comment: The SQL query `SELECT name FROM your_database.your_table WHERE area='mubia';` is where you need to start. Pass this from your database as an array and then get PHP to do the work. Look up how CodeIgniter selects database records - for instance: https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/examples.html

Comment: Thanks to reply me guys. maximedubois i tried this using multiple query one is for particular area and second is for any random data. And count the first one if it is less than 5 then i append second one. But this is too lengthy and i was thinking to do this in single query but i could not find any perfect query to do this so i share my problem with you. But thanks for give your valuable time. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use order and limit. Something like this:

```
select *
from your_table
order by case when area = 'mumbai' then 1 else 2 end
limit 5;
```

The above case expression will keep the given area at the top and others after that. The limit 5 clause will pick first 5 of the ordered rows.